# Can some one tell me Why This is Query are very slow?

Tags: mysql, database

Can some one explain why this query with IN clause over 5000 record are too slow?

Table strucuture

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `wp_transactions_log` (
  `sync_sequence` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'the sequence number of the sync process/operation that this transaction belong to ',
  `objectid` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'the entity/record id',
  `wp_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `table_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL COMMENT 'the target wordpress table name this transaction occured/fail for some reason',
  `logical_table_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `operation` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'inser/update/delete',
  `status` varchar(20) NOT NULL COMMENT 'status of the transaction: success,fail',
  `fail_count` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL COMMENT 'how many this transaction failed',
  `fail_description` text NOT NULL COMMENT 'a description of the failure',
  `createdon` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sync_sequence`,`objectid`,`table_name`,`operation`,`wp_id`),
  KEY `objectid` (`objectid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

This table contain 5k record.

The query :

```
SELECT wp_id,objectId FROM wp_transactions_log WHERE `operation` = "insert" AND `wp_id` != 0 AND `status` != "ignore" AND `table_name` ='itg_wpclass_dates' AND objectId IN (... 5k record)
```

even this query are same:

```
SELECT wp_id,objectId FROM wp_transactions_log WHERE  objectId IN (5k record)
```

Note: all the parameters in the IN clauses are themselves the same in the table rows. 
I mean by slow it takes more than 15 Sec.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226035/why-does-a-query-slow-down-drastically-if-in-the-where-clause-a-constant-is-repl

Comment: too slow you mean how many seconds? I did a similar test years ago, used 10K in `IN` clause and executed in `0.04` seconds. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7818697/153723 I believe problem is not the table.

Comment: No it's more than 15 seconds

Comment: did you try to repair table?

Comment: How you obtain the 5k record .. if you use a subselect please add to your  question the related  code ..

Comment: No this query is constructed grammatically, so the query is like this, no sub query are included.

Comment: @Ergec what did you mean by repair the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query are fast it take to 200ms to exectue, but the time for processing the query and retrieving the data are the long. I think there's no way to reduce this time.

Answer (score 2):

objectid is not indexed. Composite primary key is indexed only. Add index on objectid and then try.

```
ALTER TABLE wp_transactions_log ADD INDEX (objectid);
```

Although if you have huge data, then adding index will lock your metadata, use **INPLACE** algorithm to do it with minimum lock contention.

Also, before youe select statement, just add Explain and provide us the response. It will be a good metrics to identify issue in your table.

Comment: I created index on objectid but that's useless.

Comment: Can you show the result of Explain SELECT wp_id,objectId FROM wp_transactions_log WHERE  objectId IN (5k record)

Comment: Here's the result:

id | select_type| table| type| possible_keys| key| key_len| ref| rows| Extra
1 |SIMPLE| wp_transactions_log| index| objectid| objectid| 402| NULL| 5000| Using where; Using index